# How to fill previous value in a downwards direction in a dataframe till last numeric value of a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame

```
df= data.frame(d= c("90-1","90-2","90-3","90-4","90-5","91-5","91-6"),
              a=c(NA,NA,150,NA,1,NA,3),
              b=c(1.0,NA,90.7,30.5,NA,NA,NA),
              c=c(NA,NA,1000,2,4,NA,NA))
```

Here the 1st column is a non-null column.
I want to fill the previous value if NA till the last numeric value of each column i.e from 2nd column to ncol(df).

**Required Output**

```
df_result= data.frame(d= c("90-1","90-2","90-3","90-4","90-5","91-5","91-6"),
               a=c(NA,NA,150,150,1,1,3),
               b=c(1.0,1.0,90.7,30.5,NA,NA,NA),
               c=c(NA,NA,1000,2,4,NA,NA))
```

**Code Tried**
rev(which(df$b>0))[1] would give me the last non numeric value of column b.
And fill function from tidyr would work But I don't know how to combine the two.

Any approach would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. So this `df %>% group_by(d) %>% fill(everything())` wouldn't work for you?

Comment: No it's not working.  I want to fill, till last numeric row of a column.  example rev(which(df$b>0))[1]  would give result 4. which means i would only fill column b till 4th row. And this logic has to be applied on all the column @Sotos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one trick to do this.

For each column from `a:c` we replace the `NA` values after the last numeric value to string `"NA"`, use `fill` to replace real `NA` values and change the `"NA"` value back to real `NA`'s.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(a:c, ~replace(., is.na(.) & 
                row_number() > max(which(!is.na(.))), "NA"))) %>%
  fill(a:c) %>%
  mutate(across(a:c, ~replace(., . == 'NA', NA))) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

#     d   a    b    c
#1 90-1  NA  1.0   NA
#2 90-2  NA  1.0   NA
#3 90-3 150 90.7 1000
#4 90-4 150 30.5    2
#5 90-5   1   NA    4
#6 91-5   1   NA   NA
#7 91-6   3   NA   NA
```